# What types of aircraft can TS-1 fuel be used for?

Tags: aircraft-design, russia, jet-fuel, su-30

I'm curious to learn about what types of military aircraft can take TS-1 fuel. For example, can a SU-30 or a YAK-130 use TS-1, or do they only take A-1? Also what types of helicopters can take TS-1?

Can TS-1 be used in any civilian aircraft?

Answer (score 1):

TS-1 can be used in any *subsonic* turbine-powered aircraft.

Note that the second of your questions has already been asked: [Can TS-1 fuel be used in an aircraft that takes Jet A?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/77245/can-ts-1-fuel-be-used-in-an-aircraft-that-takes-jet-a)
I'll add a brief note - all civilian jet aircraft are subsonic, so they can *technically operate* on TS-1 fuel, even if only approved for RT. Unapproved but compatible fuels can result in shortened maintenance intervals.

[Here is a brief list of all Russian jet fuel types](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD#%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%A2%D0%A1-1). TS-1 has a very low freezing point, [below -60C](https://www.booksite.ru/fulltext/1/001/008/095/803.htm), allowing for cold weather operation. But the lower the freezing point, the lower the flashpoint, so a light fuel like TS-1 is more hazardous than Jet-A in hot weather. RT fuel is used for that.

For the same reason, TS-1 is not recommended for supersonic flight, where the fuel heats up and light fuels can boil off. If combat is possible on the mission, the Su-30 and other supersonic aircraft need to use the more versatile **RT fuel**, which has a higher boiling temperature.

Supercruising aircraft like the Tu-160 or SR-71 get even hotter, so they need heavier fuels, such as T-6, T-8 or JP-7, that can take higher temperatures. These fuels are not suitable for subsonic civilian aircraft.